# How long can I visit the UK within one year's time?

Tags: visas, uk, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen w/ a Canadian passport.

I went on a student visitor visa from September 11 2014 to December 17 2014. I'm returning on May 2 and leaving July 30 of this year as a tourist. How long am I able to visit the UK within a 365 day period? Does the fact that there is a period of time between my visits change anything?

I know I'm only allowed to stay as a general visitor/tourist for 6 months at a time. But as these two separate trips total just over 6 months, I am concerned that I will not be allowed to stay this long.

Comment: The rules do not mention anything about a 365 day period.

Answer (score 1):

**How long am I able to visit the UK within a 365 day period?** 
Maximum stay of 6 months.

**Does the fact that there is a period of time between my visits change anything?**
When you're not staying for more than 6 months, there's no point in being worried about it. You can visit UK over a tourist/visit visa for as many times as you want. All you need to be careful about is that your stay doesn't exceed the limit of 6 months.
Ref: https://www.gov.uk/general-visit-visa

I hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure?  I can see where it says "You can stay for a maximum of 6 months on each visit".  But where do the rules mention a 365 day period?  Or alternatively, where do the rules stipulate anything about accumulating time in the UK  over multiple visits?

Comment: This was what I was curious about. A lot of sources online mention this 180 days per year rule, but the official uk border website only states 6 months at a time.